# How to modify a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods, overriding, final

I have the following class called `A`, with the method `getValue()`:

```
public class A {
    public final int getValue() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

The method `getValue()` always returns ***3***, then i have another class called `B`, i need to implement something to access to the method `getValue()` in the class `A`, but i need to return ***4*** instead ***3***.

Class `B`:

```
public class B {
  public static A getValueA() {
    return new A();
  }
}
```

The main class `ATest`:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        A a = B.getValueA();
        assertEquals(
            a.getValue() == 4,
            Boolean.TRUE
        );
    }
}
```

I tried to override the method, but really i dont know how to get what i want. Any question post in comments.

Comment: That method cannot be overriden. It's  `final`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override the method, because it is `final`. Had it not been `final`, you could do this:

```
public static A getValueA() {
    return new A() {
        // Will not work with getValue marked final
        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return 4;
        }
    };
}
```

This approach creates an anonymous subclass inside `B`, overrides the method, and returns an instance to the caller. The override in the anonymous subclass returns `4`, as required.

Comment: @TimeToCode It's already there: copy-paste the function `getValueA` into your class `B`, remove `final` from `A`'s `getValue`, compile, and it will do what you want. The curly braces after `new A ()` is the body of the anonymous class extending `A`.

Comment: But the method should be final, this is a restriction for the problem :/

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible.  Given `A` as you have written it now, `someA.getValue()` is always going to return 3, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at what you're doing: You've given the class B a factory method to create a new instance of class A. But this is not changing anything on the implementation of the method `getValue()`.

Try this:

Remove the final modifier from method `getValue()` in class A.

Then let class B extend/inherit class A.

```
public class B extends A {
  @Override
  public int getValue() {
    return 4;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help...   =)

Best regards

Alex

Comment: Yes, its obviously, but i have the restriction that the method in class A should be final always..

Comment: Okay, I've to admit, that dasblinkenlight was faster and also has the correct answer...What a shame...   =/

Comment: @TimeToCode If you need that method to be final, you can't do what you want. Both answers won't work with that method marked final.