# Can't cast org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager

Tags: java, dom, batik

I am patching org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager by overriding method

```
@Override
public void interrupt() { ... }
```

to avoid

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RunnableQueue not started or has exited
at org.apache.batik.util.RunnableQueue.invokeLater(RunnableQueue.java:277)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The new class is

```
public class SVGUpdateManager extends org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager
```

When calling from JSVGCanvas

```
SVGUpdateManager um = (SVGUpdateManager) getUpdateManager();
```

I get a java.lang.ClassCastException, org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager cannot be cast to SVGUpdateManager

Comment: You cannot cast a superclass to a subclass, only a subclass to a superclass. Could you paste your getUpdateManager() function to give me more details so I van help you?

Comment: From : https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/swing/svg/JSVGComponent.html#getUpdateManager()

Comment: JSVGCanvas.getUpdateManager
public UpdateManager getUpdateManager()
Returns the current update manager. The update manager becomes available after the first rendering completes. ....

Comment: An alternate question is: how do you patch a library, specifically : org.apache.batik.bridge.UpdateManager;

Answer (score 1):

Okay so according to your comment, the problem is that you cannot cast a superclass to a subclass, only a subclass to a superclass.

For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B castedA = (A) a; // casting is unnecessary
        B b = new B();
        A castedB = (A) b; // class cast exception
    }

    public static class B {

    }

    public static class A extends B {

    }
}
```

I think you should instantiate and UpdateManager, and wrap it in your custom class (not extend it's functionality). Then proxy out the original instance's functions.

Or you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432938/how-to-modify-a-method-from-another-class)